# amount of generated entity in scala check

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I have a scalacheck test with `case class Payment` Seq and I want to check and generate `Seq` with 10,000 elements. Could you tell me please how to control the amount of elements in `Seq` in test?

```
import org.scalacheck.{Arbitrary, Gen}

  test("payment test") {
    implicit val arbitraryEntityType: Arbitrary[Payment] = Arbitrary(genPayment)

    forAll { (payment: Seq[Payment]) =>


implicit val genUserId: Gen[Int] = Gen.oneOf(10010 to 30000)

implicit val genVisaType: Gen[String] = Gen.oneOf("VISA", "MASTER")

case class Payment(
    user_id: Int,
    pay_doc_type: String,
    .... )


implicit val genPayment: Gen[Payment] = for {
  user_id      <- genUserId
  pay_doc_type <- genVisaType
} yield Payment(
  user_id,
  pay_doc_type,
)
```

Comment: Also Payment contains amount and date

Comment: I'm sorry if it sounds too silly, but since you have `Seq[Payment]` in forAll, can you limit the amount via `take`? Like: forAll { (payment: Seq[Payment]) => payment.take(10_000) ...

Comment: @TomerShetah yeah, grand thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`containerOfN`](https://github.com/typelevel/scalacheck/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scalacheck/Gen.scala#L833):

```
import org.scalacheck.Gen.containerOfN

implicit val limitedPayments: Gen[Seq[Payment]] = containerOfN[Seq, Payment](10000, genPayment)
```